# How to access elements in vectors in Lists more efficiently?

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I have a problem where I want to combine a list of vectors, all of the same type, in a particular fashion.  I want the first element of my resultant vector to be the first element of the first vector in my list, the second element should be the first element of the second vector, the third, the first of the third and so on until n where n is length of my list and then element n+1 should be the second element of the first vector.  This repeats until finished.

Currently, I am doing it like this:

```
CharacterVector measure(nrows * expansion);
CharacterVector temp(nrows);
for(int i=0; i < measure.size(); i++){
  temp = values[i % expansion];
  measure[i] = temp[i / expansion];
}
return(measure);
```

Where `values` is the `List` of `CharacterVectors`.  This seems incredibly inefficient, overwriting `temp` every single time but I don't know of a better way to access the elements in `values`.  I don't know a lot of C++ but I assume there must be a better way.

Any and all help is greatly appreciate!

EDIT:
All vectors in '`values` are of the same length `nrows` and `values` has `expansion` elements in it.

Comment: First of all, if your list of charactervectors can be modified i would always use myvector = mylist.front(); and mylist.pop_front(); afterwards. You can preconstruct the vector and can easily know at which positions the elements of this vector should go.. i.e. vector[0], vector[n+1] etc.. where n = mylist.size(). Here i assume of course that each vector in the list has equal size.

Comment: You have a list with random access operators?

Comment: @cageman That's a good point.  I don't need to iterate through each vector like I am now.  It's mathematically trivial to go from the first vector and load it into the result in all the right places.

Comment: @DDrmmr I'm not sure what you mean?  I guess that I should make it more clear that `List` values is an `Rcpp::List`.

Comment: @iShouldUseAName And what is `Rcpp::List`? Please don't ask people to guess and just post compilable code.

Comment: @DDrmmr If you aren't familiar with `R` and/or `Rcpp` I'm not really going to be able to explain in a reasonable amount of space, or frankly, point to good documentation for it since I don't have it. Sorry.

Comment: @iShouldUseAName the point is that when speaking of vectors and lists in a C++ context, most of us will assume std::vector and std::list, so specifying Rcpp::List seems logical, so we don't give wrong answers.  When possible, at least pointing to documentation would be helpful too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is the `ListOf<CharacterVector>` class. As the name implies, it represents an R list which only contains `CharacterVector`.

The code below uses it to extract the second element of each character vector from the list. Should not be hard to adapt it to your expansion algorithm, but your example was not reproducible without a bit more context.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp ;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
CharacterVector second( ListOf<CharacterVector> values ){
    int n = values.size() ;
    CharacterVector res(n);
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
      res[i] = values[i][1] ;
    }
    return res ;
}
```

Then, you `sourceCpp` this and try it on some sample data:

```
> data <- list(letters, letters, LETTERS)

> second(data)
[1] "b" "b" "B"
```

Now about your assumption:

> This seems incredibly inefficient, overwriting temp every single time

Creating a `CharacterVector` is pretty fast, there is no deep copy of data, so this should not have been an issue in the first place.

Comment: Excellent!  This is exactly what I was looking for in terms of syntax.  As to your point that overwriting temp is not a very costly operation, when I changed it so that I only did so 4 times instead of `nrows * expansion` I increased the speed of my target function by 3 fold.  This seems fairly significant to me.  Perhaps there was something elese about that change that brought about the efficienct gain?  Additionally, I attempted to implement an answer similar to cagemans answer below but got a compiler error on the line where he has `CharacterVector&`.  Any ideas why?

Comment: Also thanks a TON for all you've done for `R`! Between `Rcpp` and `dplyr` you've made a huge impact!  It's greatly appreciated! Loving learning `Rcpp`!

Comment: By 4 times I actually mean `expansion` times.  4 Was the value of `expansion` in my test case.

Answer (score 1):

You can preconstruct the vector and can easily know at which positions the elements of the first vector should go.. i.e. measure[0], measure[n], measure[n*2] etc.. where n = mylist.size(). Here i assume of course that each vector in the list has equal size. Untested code:

```
CharacterVector measure(nrows * expansion);
for(int i=0; i < values.size(); ++i)
{
  CharacterVector& temp = values[i];
  int newPosition = i;
  for( int j=0; j < temp.size(); ++j)
  {
    measure[newPosition ] = temp[j];
    newPosition += expansion;
  }
}

return(measure);
```

Comment: Each vector does have the same length.  I would check your math on the insertion of elements into `measure` though.

Comment: Thanks, i think the code is correct. Just my comment was wrong :) Still untested though.

Comment: It's close to being right but not exactly.  You would quickly end up with an index beyond the size of `measure` as is. Your `+= nrows` should likely by `+= expansion`.